# Prisma query for returning a better response in Nest Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nestjs, prisma

Backend:

```
const specificStudentAssignments =
  await this.prisma.classesToStudents.findMany({
    where: {
      studentId: +studentId,
      classStatus: 'completed',
    },
    select: {
      classes: {
        select: {
          projects: {
            include: {
              students: {
                where: {
                  studentId: +studentId,
                },
              },
            },
          },
          quizzes: {
            include: {
              students: {
                where: {
                  studentId: +studentId,
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

This query works fine.

```
[
{
    "classes": {
        "projects": {
            "projectId": 13,
            "classId": 10,
            "projectTitle": "New Project",
            "projectDescription": "New Project Description",
            "startDate": "2023-02-21",
            "endDate": "2023-02-23",
            "totalMarks": 10,
            "file": "uploads\\file-1676991631319code-example.pdf",
            "fileName": "code-example.pdf",
            "students": [
                {
                    "projectId": 13,
                    "studentId": 1,
                    "teacherId": 3,
                    "obtainedMarks": null,
                    "result": null,
                    "creativity": 0,
                    "logic": 0,
                    "completion": 0,
                    "review": null,
                    "status": "pending"
                }
            ]
        },
        "quizzes": {
            "quizId": 10,
            "classId": 10,
            "quizTitle": "New Class Quiz",
            "quizDescription": "New Description",
            "submitDate": "2023-02-21",
            "startTime": "23:59",
            "endTime": "22:59",
            "totalMarks": null,
            "students": [
                {
                    "quizId": 10,
                    "studentId": 1,
                    "obtainedMarks": 0,
                    "result": "",
                    "status": "pending"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
{
    "classes": {
        "projects": {
            "projectId": 14,
            "classId": 13,
            "projectTitle": "New Project Class 2",
            "projectDescription": "New Project",
            "startDate": "2023-02-21",
            "endDate": "2023-02-24",
            "totalMarks": 10,
            "file": "uploads\\file-1676997922198CV_Mohsin (1).pdf",
            "fileName": "CV_Mohsin (1).pdf",
            "students": [
                {
                    "projectId": 14,
                    "studentId": 1,
                    "teacherId": 3,
                    "obtainedMarks": null,
                    "result": null,
                    "creativity": 0,
                    "logic": 0,
                    "completion": 0,
                    "review": null,
                    "status": "pending"
                }
            ]
        },
        "quizzes": {
            "quizId": 11,
            "classId": 13,
            "quizTitle": "New Class Quiz",
            "quizDescription": "New Quiz Description",
            "submitDate": "2023-02-21",
            "startTime": "21:43",
            "endTime": "13:43",
            "totalMarks": null,
            "students": [
                {
                    "quizId": 11,
                    "studentId": 1,
                    "obtainedMarks": 0,
                    "result": "",
                    "status": "pending"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
]
```

This is response.

Frontend:

```
  assignments[key]?.classes?.projects?.students[0]?.status
```

My problem is I do not want to use students[0] to access the status everytime. Is there a better way to do this? I know I can iterate through the returned result of query and make this specific array in the parent object and use it. But when we use loop it will slow the api response. I want to know something better for performance is there any way to do it and also do not want to use student[0] each time?

Comment: Hi Moshin. I wouldn't worry too much about iterating over your students regarding performance. Your real bottleneck here will come from your query. You might want to paginate it as a first step.

Quick question: Are you exposing directly your prisma response to your frontend, without any DTO?

Comment: I am using dto's for requests , and returning the response directly. Can you share an example of returning response with dto's. 

If the performance is not an issue here can you tell how can I change student[0].status is there any other solution..??

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to look at the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/types-and-parameters). My question was more about the fact that you could map your prisma values, and simplify your frontend data access. 

That being said, while trying to reproduce your schema I noticed that you might have a denormalization problem. For starter, it's a bit strange to query `classes`, that will only return one object per entry.

Comment: Can you help writing better relations... i can show use my schema for this...! how can i better those relations...! i think i normalized each thing to max...! but maybe i am wrong...!

Comment: kindly provide me your email so that i can send you detailed information if possible ... thank you

Comment: Hi Moshin. In my opinion Stack Overflow is first an foremost an tool to share knowledge to a wide audience. Keeping this conversation private would not benefit future developers (including ourselves) stumbling on the same difficulties. I understand that you would feel safer, and more at ease sharing private details in a private conversation though. We don't need all the details to help you. 

Regarding your question, I'd say that optimizing your schema depends a lot on your stack. Are you using prisma with a relational Db ?

Comment: yes i am using prisma in Nest Js

Comment: nest.js is a web framework. You could be using prisma with mongo db. I'm assuming that you are using Postgresql, but I could be wrong.

Comment: yes using postgresql

Comment: Ok, regarding your initial request, you can't access directly the status because you have 1 to n relations between your quizzes and students, and between your projects and students. 

If you are trying to retrieve the queried student status, maybe you should try a `findUnique` or `findFirst`, otherwise you'll always get an array.

If what you need is direct access to the status, you can transform your prisma output into intelligible data for your frontend, which would be doable as a quick win. I'm going to write a deeper answer as a stack overflow answer.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in my previous comment, you can't access directly the student's status, since you have *1 to n* relations between quizzed and students, and between projects and students.

Since your student is also linked to your `ClassesToStudents` model, you could retrieve the student's status directly from it, instead of filtering in your sub models

```
const data = prisma.classesToStudents.findMany({
  where: { studentId: +studentId, classStatus: 'completed' },
  include: {
     student: true,
     // with your other conditions
     classes: { include: { quizzes: true, projects: true } 
  },
})
const status = data.student.status;
```

On the other hand, you could keep your current request, and map the data in your nestjs response:

```
@Controller('classes')
export class ClassController {
  constructor(
     private readonly prismaService: PrismaService,
  ) {}

  @Get('/:studentId')
  async getCompletedClassesForStudent(
     @Param('studentId', ParseIntPipe) studentId: number
  ) {
    // your request
    const classes = await this.prisma.findMany({ ... });

    return classes.map(({ classes }) => ({
       status: classes?.projects?.students[0]?.status,
       classes
    });
  }
}
```

You don't *need* a DTO to strongly type your return value, but I would strongly advise you to use one for maintenance purposes.